# Is there any way to show the pointer when using Android Studio Device Mirroring?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio Device Mirroring to capture my physical device screen.
I have the `show taps` option set to `On` on my device, and I've emphasized both the pointer color and size. While I'm able to see the pointer on my phone, it disappears whenever I start recording the screen.

Is there any method to display the pointer while recording the screen using Android Studio Device Mirroring?